# VBScript If Instr with a recordset

Tags: vbscript, compare, recordset

I am trying to do an if statement with a recordset within VBScript to do a "like" compare a recordset.

```
While Not rs.EOF
    result = result & "<tr style='" & FontStyle(FontFamily, FontSize) & _
             " background-color: " & RowColors(number mod 2) & "'>" &_
             Tdc(number) & Td(rs("Name")) & Tdc(rs("Machine Type")) & _
             Tdc(ChooseStatusColor(rs("Backup Status"))) & _
             Tdc(rs("Backup State")) & Td(rs("Last Backup Start")) & _
             Td(rs("Last Backup End")) & _
             If InStr(rs("Next Backup"), "*M") > 0 Then Td(rs("Next Backup")) Else Td(rs("Next Backup")) & "12:00:00 AM" & _
             End If &_
             "</tr>"
    rs.MoveNext
    number = number + 1
Wend
```

If I use just `Td(rs("Next Backup")) & "12:00:00 AM"  &_` it works fine but if I add the compare `If Instr(rs("Next Backup"), "*M") > 0 then Td(rs("Next Backup")) Else Td(rs("Next Backup")) & "12:00:00 AM"  &_`, I get a VB compilation error.  I am not sure where the error is in this logic or if I can even use a recordset in an InStr function.  What am I doing wrong here?

I get the same result when I use multiple lines:

```
While Not rs.EOF
    result = result & "<tr style='" & FontStyle(FontFamily, FontSize) & _
             " background-color: " & RowColors(number mod 2) & "'>" & _
             Tdc(number) & Td(rs("Name")) & Tdc(rs("Machine Type")) & _
             Tdc(ChooseStatusColor(rs("Backup Status"))) & _
             Tdc(rs("Backup State")) & Td(rs("Last Backup Start")) & _
             Td(rs("Last Backup End")) & _
             If InStr(1, (rs("Next Backup")), "*M") > 0 Then & _
             Td(rs("Next Backup")) & _
             Else Td(rs("Next Backup")) & "12:00:00 AM" & _
             End If &_
             "</tr>"
    rs.MoveNext
    number = number + 1
Wend
```

Comment: The error is with your If statement.  Break it into multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inline conditionals like that in VBScript. Change your code to something like this:

```
While Not rs.EOF
    result = result & "<tr style='" & FontStyle(FontFamily, FontSize) & _
             " background-color: " & RowColors(number mod 2) & "'>" & _
             Tdc(number) & Td(rs("Name")) & Tdc(rs("Machine Type")) & _
             Tdc(ChooseStatusColor(rs("Backup Status"))) & _
             Tdc(rs("Backup State")) & Td(rs("Last Backup Start")) & _
             Td(rs("Last Backup End"))
    If InStr(rs("Next Backup"), "M") > 0 Then
        result = result & Td(rs("Next Backup"))
    Else
        result = result & Td(rs("Next Backup") & "12:00:00 AM")
    End If
    result = result & "</tr>"
    rs.MoveNext
    number = number + 1
Wend
```

Comment: Actually that adds the "12:00:00 AM" regardless if there is a "*M*" in the rs("Next Backup")  Here are two examples:
 
`RS1 2/1/2018 9:00:00 AM
12:00:00 AM

RS2 2/1/2018
12:00:00 AM`

Comment: @pinchepooch `InStr` doesn't do wildcard or regular expression matches. `*M` is looking for an asterisk followed by the capital letter `M`. If you want to check for the presence of a letter `M` you need to remove the asterisk.

Comment: You wouldn't so happen to know why it is line breaking before the "12:00:00 AM" would you?  I have tried nowrap in the <TD> to no success.

Comment: Assuming `Td()` wraps its argument in `<td></td>` I would suspect that you need to change `Td(rs("Next Backup")) & "12:00:00 AM"` to `Td(rs("Next Backup") & "12:00:00 AM")`.

Comment: Your assumption was correct, I was looking at everything but that.  I'm done, thank you for the education.